# usort Sort Descending rather than Ascending With more than 2 Arrays

Tags: php, usort

After merging 4 arrays, I am using usort to sort the final array via the Date.  However, it sorts in ascending fashion and I need it to be Descending.  I have seen solutions for descending sorting when there are only 2 arrays being merged, but no examples of more than 2.

Each array ($files, $newfiles, $comments and $ratings) have the following fields: ID, Title, Date and Type.  I need to sort them all via Date Descending.  Here is my current code:

```
    function dateSort($a,$b,$c,$d){
$dateA = strtotime($a['Date']);
$dateB = strtotime($b['Date']);
$dateC = strtotime($c['Date']);
$dateD = strtotime($d['Date']);


 return ($dateA-$dateB-$dateC-$dateD);

  //I HAVE ALSO TRIED REVERSING THE ORDER LIKE THIS BUT NO LUCK.  
 //THE SORTING IS STRANGE AND UN ORDERED WHEN I DO THIS:
 // return ($dateD-$dateC-$dateB-$dateA);

 }

    $result = array_merge($files, $newfiles,$comments,$ratings);

    usort($result, 'dateSort');
```

Comment: you're using usort, which is **USER** sort - you're the one providing the comparison function, so it's up to YOU to modify that function to reverse the sort direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$descending_array = array_reverse(usort($result, 'dateSort'));
```

This reverses the array, and thus reverses ascending order to descending.

Comment: Such a simple answer @Ali. Curious that the other answers to this question with 2 records didn't just use this method.  Thanks much!

Comment: I kinda feel like `array_reverse(usort())` version is better design compared to editing the callback function, but worse performance since PHP has to iterate over the array a second time. Maybe an intermediary callback, returning `-(cmp(a, b))`, would be the best compromise.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but it came up near the top of some search results.

I've not tested this but the callable part of `usort` will iterate over whatever array you have provided. It doesn't matter if each element is an array itself.

Also in the case of the example you have provided, `DateTime` objects are comparable.

Depending on the format of the `Date` field, you could try using the space ship operator in php 7:

```php
usort($result, function($a, $b) {
    return new \DateTime( $a['Date'] ) <=> new \DateTime( $b['Date'] );
});
```

This would return the array sorted in **ascending** order. Reversing the comparison will return it in **descending**.

```php
usort($result, function($a, $b) {
    return new \DateTime( $b['Date'] ) <=> new \DateTime( $a['Date'] );
});
```